# C# Windows Form Application --> Switching Between Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am developing Windows Form Application using Microsoft Visual C# 2010
I have two forms I made through Visual Studio GUI now I want to switch to next form on Button Click event `this.hide()` works but when I write next form name followed by dot than `show()` method does not show it seems show method is not available for it. 
How can I show my new Form as It is not dynamically created I have already created it through Visual Studio GUI
When I Create It Dynamically As

```
Form myform = new Form();
```

than

`myform.show();`

show function exists but in my case this does not exists

Kindly tell me what's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an object of your second form then call `Show()` method

```
SecondForm frmsecond = new SecondForm();
frmsecond.Show();
```

`Form myform = new Form();` is not needed here because you are trying to make myform as an object of Form Class

Answer (score 9):

You need to create an object of the Form2 and call the show method on instance of Form2

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.Show();
```

**EDIT:** Since you edited your question and added the part `Form myform = new Form();`. You are actually creating an instance of base class `Form`. You need to create the instance of your Form which is inheriting `Form` class.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
```

You need to create instance of Form2 class in this case. But your myForm should have Show method. Are you sure you have `System.Windows.Forms;` in using statement and Form class is from the `System.Windows.Forms;`. Try

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form myform = new Form(); //Although this is wrong but it should have show method
myform.Show();
```

Comment: But I have Already Applied All The Length Width Height Background Image Also All Other Things Through GUI How I Can DO It Through It Check back my question thoroughly and identify what's the real problem

Answer (score 1):

well.. 'you have two forms (and you are not creating them dynamically), and you want to switch from one to another on a click event', isn't ?

For example,consider you have created two forms namely Form1 and Form2 through VS GUI. And if you like to do something like

```
Form2.Show();
```

then you can't. Have you looked at your application' entry point, ie. Main() method of your application(is in 'Program.cs' most of the cases). Though you have created your Form1 statically, you will find

```
  Application.Run(new Form1);
```

You got it now. You cant use a 'type'. You should use a variable.For that reason only we are creating the instance of your second Form and showing it.

```
Form2 form=new Form2();
form.Show();
```